# Using ASP.Net Membership, get all users

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I'm trying to use `Membership.GetAllUsers()` to create a list of all of my users in the database. However, I have a model that I use that maps out the user properties (First Name, Last Name, Email, etc.).

How can I add all of the users into `List<ManageUserViewModel>`.

I've already tired:

```
List<ManageUserViewModel> model = Membership.GetAllUsers();
```

and then

```
MembershipUserCollection users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
List<ManageUserViewModel> model = new List<ManageUserViewModel>();

foreach (var item in users)
{
    model.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're explicit with the object type in the foreach loop, you'll be able to access the user object you're looking for.

For example:

```
    var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();

    var userList = new List<MembershipUser>();
    foreach (MembershipUser user in users) 
    {
        userList.Add(user);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Membership.GetAllUsers()` returns a `MembershipUserCollection` which in practice is a list of `MembershipUser`, whereas you want a list of `ManageUserViewModel` which I assume is an internal class to your application.

You can use LINQ for this:

```
var model = Membership.GetAllUsers()
              .Select(m => 
                    new ManageUserViewModel {/* set properties you need here */ }
              )
              .ToList();
```

Which is the equivalent of:

```
var users = Membership.GetAllUsers();
var model = new List<ManageUserViewModel>();

foreach (var item in users)
{
    model.Add(new ManageUserViewModel { /* set properties here */});
}
```

Comment: When I try to assign properties from item to model, I'm not able too because item doesn't have an properties (First name, last name, etc.)

Comment: The item has all the properties of a [Membership user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser(v=vs.110).aspx) which do not include a profile. It's a separate component from membership, what are you using for it?

Comment: I'm trying to create a way to manage users in my application. Lock them, reset their password, update their role, etc. However, right now I'm just trying to get all of the users to display them to a grid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge. mine was with vb not c# and .NEt version 4.5 using visual studio 2013.
 I got all the solution from Microsoft website [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy8swhya(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)
best of luck